# Different types of ampersand symbols

Tags: symbols

So I'm aware that \& can be used to produce the traditional ampersand symbol, however I would like to use the type of ampersand symbol which looks something like a cursive E, here is a picture:

[image]

Does anyone know a package which has this symbol?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `\textit{\&}`?

Comment: @Mico, That just slants it.

Comment: I just did, is there a particular font you're using where that works?

Comment: I'm using Times Roman, I don't know what font family

Comment: Try `{\usefont{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{it} \&}` or `{\usefont{OT1}{cmr}{m}{it} \&}`.

Comment: It "works" for me with Computer Modern, Times Roman (via the `newtxtext` package), and Palatino (via the `newpxtext` package).

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina, your first suggestion worked, how do you know what fonts will do that?

Comment: @banned there is no way of knowing unless you know the font, it is just a feature of the font like knowing whether g has a closed loop or any other letter shape, generally "italic" fonts are more likely to use the more open shape but it's up to the font designer

Comment: @David Carlisle okie dokie

Comment: You can always upload a symbol to whatthefont. Did that with your image: http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch[0]=%26&wtfserver=wtf_e_41&id=000b14ce535186d5000a40200000712c&glyphcount=1&imageid=0&x=91&y=42

Comment: I'm going to offer a different point of view: Worrying about the exact font is not the TeX/LaTeX way. You as the author should not care about such details. If you are writing an informal (non-published) document, why do you care? Thinking about those details detracts from thinking about the content (which should be your primary concern). If you are writing a document that will be published, you should **not** care about fonts. Worrying about those details is the job of the publisher, not the author.

Comment: Some history: http://www.shadycharacters.co.uk/2011/06/the-ampersand-part-1-of-2/,  http://www.shadycharacters.co.uk/2011/06/the-ampersand-part-2-of-2/,  http://www.typography.com/blog/our-middle-name and http://www.signalinc.com/the-strange-history-of-the-ampersand/

Answer (score 19):

You've indicated in a comment that you use Times (New) Roman as your text font. Most Times Roman-like fonts do not provide a "swashy" ampersand character, but the `newtx` font package does. :-) The following MWE shows both the italic and "normal" form of the character that's produced by this font family:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\textit{\&} vs.\ \&
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* If the character shown above is not "swashy" enough for your taste you could try a font such as `Palatino` or `Caslon`. (The screenshot you provided in your posting would seem to come from the font `Adobe Caslon Pro`.) Note that some of the swashy ampersands employ a fancy combination of an uppercase `E` and a lowercase `t`, whereas others consist of an equally fancy combination of a lowercase `e` and a lowercase `t`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} \textit{\&}
\setmainfont{Palatino nova} \textit{\&}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} \textit{\&} % a Palatino clone
\setmainfont{Adobe Caslon Pro} \textit{\&}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond} \textit{\&}

\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro} \textit{\&}
\setmainfont{ITC Galliard Std} \textit{\&}
\setmainfont{Junicode} \textit{\&}
\end{document}
```

(To compile the preceding MWE use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX; pdfLaTeX won't work. Of course, you'll also have to have the various fonts installed on your system.)

And, if you have access to `Zapfino` you can choose from seven [7!] different variants of `&`:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Zapfino}
\begin{document}
\addfontfeature{Variant=1} \&
\addfontfeature{Variant=2} \&
\addfontfeature{Variant=3} \&
\addfontfeature{Variant=4} \&
\addfontfeature{Variant=5} \&
\addfontfeature{Variant=6} \&
\addfontfeature{Variant=7} \&
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For no less than 52 Goudy ampersands, see [Goudy Aries](https://p22.com/family-Goudy_Aries); Goudy needed them for a study he wrote on the ampersand.

Comment: @Thérèse - That's a really good one! And I thought `Zapfino` was overdoing it a wee bit by offering seven different ampersands...

Answer (score 8):

Next to Mico's great answer, I just would like to show you the closest to your picture in pure pdfLaTeX. Your symbol is an [Adobe Caslon Italic](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?event=displayFont&code=CASP10005300) which has to be purchased. The most similar to get really easy would be [EB Garamond](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/) which you may use like:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\begin{document}
\textit{\&}
\end{document}
```

[image]