# The & in LaTeX papers

Tags: symbols

I need to use the `&` symbol in my thesis. But when it is used in other environments, the look changes.

```
This is a \& test. This is a \textit{\&} test.
```

[image]

The above is just an example. This symbol is included in my work unit.

```
\IEEEcompsocitemizethanks{\IEEEcompsocthanksitem my_name are with the
Department of Computer Science \& Technology, University,  \protect\\
}}
```

The `&` above will also become that weird look. Is there any solution? thanks!

Comment: `\textnormal{\&}` may work.

Comment: The appearance depends on the font family you’ve chosen to use. The ampersand (a ligature of `e` and `t`) can have many forms: Goudy wrote a book about it, and several fonts exist which contain only various styles of ampersand.

Comment: The look of `&`  shouldn't be your concern. You (or the publisher) decide which font to use, and the font designer has decided how the symbols look like. The italic version is closer to the origin of `&`, which is the Latin word `et` (and).

Comment: that is a fairly standard italic & the shape changes just as  g may get a closed descender in some styles

Comment: "This is a \textit{\&} test." would be weird for the same reason that "This is a \& \textit{t}est." would be weird - you don't usually change fonts for a single character.  "\textit{This is \& a test.}" would be fine.  "\textit{This is a }\&\textit{ test.}" is weird again.

Comment: Did you see the posting [Different types of ampersand symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180718/5001)?

Comment: Perhaps `\textsl{\&}`

Comment: If you think about it, really weird  is that "e" plus "t"  look like an eight with feet. The italic version still looks like a handwritten "et". Less frequent, but not more odd.